# Delaying Angular application start until promise resolves?

Tags: angular

Currently, I have this:

```
new Loader().load().then(() => {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  });
```

The problem is that I don't necessarily need to delay everything until the promise resolves, just `ngOnInit` and any route resolving. I'd like to allow any other angular2 setup that ISN'T routing or rendering, but block those until a promise resolves. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: This is exactly what APP_INITIALIZER is for, as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using APP_INITIALIZER**

First option would be to use the [`APP_INITIALIZER`](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER). With this you can do initial stuff, before the `AppComponent` gets bootstrapped:

```
@NgModule({
    // ...
    providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
            useFactory: appInitFactory, 
            deps: [AppInitService],
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

With the `deps` array you can inject services you might need inside your factory:

```
export function appInitFactory(appInitService: AppInitService): () => Promise<any> {
    return () => appInitService.initializeApplication();
}
```

You have to return an (arrow) function with this.

**Using the Router config**

Second option, if you use the `Router` is to set the `initialNavigation` to `false` in your [`forRoot`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#forRoot) call on the `RouterModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
       RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, {initialNavigation: false})
    ]    
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then inside your `AppComponent` you should have some service which does the `Promise` logic for you, and navigate where you want to go after its done. The 'problem' with this solution is that the `AppComponent` does get initialised, but if you only mind about the actual routes not getting resolved immediately, but do have sort of an app-shell while you wait for the resolving, you can use this

Comment: I initially tried APP_INITIALIZER, but it did appear that routes and guards, specifically, resolved before app initialization was complete. I can try this again.

Comment: @StefanKendall My guess is you did something wrong then :) Did you put it in the bootstrapped module? Did you put `multi: true`.. did you return a function from the `factory`, so the return type of your factory should be: `() => Promise<any>`

Comment: I imagine it could have been any of these things. I tried again and nothing seems to go awry before everything gets loaded, and loading is quite a bit faster.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't use APP_INITIALIZER inside of lazily loaded modules. Your best bet in that case would be to execute your synchronous code (no async support) in the module's constructor

Comment: @TabsNotSpaces for that you can use a route resolver